# Parse JSON file in ASP.NET MVC and display the data in the webpage

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, parsing

I have a remote URL from where I read a JSON Object that looks like this:

```
{"books":
 [
   {"title":"Book 1", "author":"Author1", "price":762, "inStock":15},
   {"title":"Book 2", "author":"Author2", "price":100, "inStock":1},
   {"title":"Book 3", "author":"Author3", "price":185.5, "inStock":5},
   {"title":"Book 4", "author":"Author 4", "price":1748, "inStock":3},
   {"title":"Book 5", "author":"Author 5", "price":999, "inStock":20},
   {"title":"Book 6", "author":"Author 6", "price":499.5, "inStock":3},
   {"title":"Book 7", "author":"Author 7", "price":564.5, "inStock":0}
 ]
}
```

I have created two classes Book.cs

```
public class Book
{
    public string title;

    public string author;

    public string price;

    public string inStock;
}
```

And Books.cs

```
public class Books
{
    public IList<Book> books { get; set; }
}
```

How to correctly parse the JSON so I can show the contents in the Razor HTML

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"http://www.myurl.json");
    Books[] books = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Books[]>(json);

    return View(books);
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Books` class already contains a collection property to represent each of your individual books, so you don't need to actually deserialize a `Books[]` but rather just a `Books` object :

```
// Since Books is already a container element, it will map the "books" property
// from your JSON object to the matching IList<Book> property
var books = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Books>(json);
```

**Example**

[image]

You can [see a complete working example of this here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lYjXhc) and the example code demonstrated in the snippet below.

```js
// YourClasses.cs
namespace Example
{
 public class Book
 {
  public string title;
 
  public string author;
 
  public string price;
 
  public string inStock;
 }
 
 public class Books
 {
  public IList<Book> books;
 }
}

// YourController.cs
namespace Example
{
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
   // Example JSON in lieu of API call
   var json = "{\"books\":[{\"title\":\"Book 1\", \"author\":\"Author1\", \"price\":762, \"inStock\":15},{\"title\":\"Book 2\", \"author\":\"Author2\", \"price\":100, \"inStock\":1},{\"title\":\"Book 3\", \"author\":\"Author3\", \"price\":185.5, \"inStock\":5},{\"title\":\"Book 4\", \"author\":\"Author 4\", \"price\":1748, \"inStock\":3},{\"title\":\"Book 5\", \"author\":\"Author 5\", \"price\":999, \"inStock\":20},{\"title\":\"Book 6\", \"author\":\"Author 6\", \"price\":499.5, \"inStock\":3},{\"title\":\"Book 7\", \"author\":\"Author 7\", \"price\":564.5, \"inStock\":0}]}"; 
   var books = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Books>(json);
   return View(books);
  }
 }
}

// Index.cshtml
@model Example.Books
<ul>
    @foreach(var book in Model.books){
  <li>@book.title</li>
 }
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want an array of `Books`.  You just want the `Books` container:

```
Books books = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Books>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Book class you need

```
public class Book
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public int inStock { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Books class you need

```
public class Books
{
    public List<Book> books { get; set; }
}
```

You need to have this in your code

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"http://www.myurl.json");
    Books books = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Books>(json);

    return View(books);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your classes are correct for your JSON, you could "paste JSON as classes" in VS pro and then deserialise.

Answer (score 0):

Declare Books as:

```
public class Books : List<Book>
```

And desrialize it as indicated by @chadnt:

```
Books books = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Books>(json);
```